# Jquery: JSON parsing always gets unexpected character error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to parse data from the server. Though I'm working on a valid JSON, I always get the `JSON unexpected character error`.

Please consider this code:

```
var shows = $.parseJSON(fetchData('contentShows', this.id)); // Returns a valid JSON data

$.each(shows, function(index, value) {
    console.log(value.id);
});

fetchData = function(dataRequest, id) {
    var data = $.ajax({
        url: '/shows.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(dataRequest);
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    return data;
}
```

This is the sample JSON:

```
[
    {"shows":[],"spool":"/home","name":"Test Name","id":2}
]
```

Comment: The quoted JSON is fine, which suggests that `fetchData` isn't returning what's quoted. What does `fetchData` look like? Could it be, for instance, that it's asynchronous?

Comment: A common cause for this is null or other special characters in the fetched data.

Comment: @T.J. There, included the fetchData function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `fetchData` function doesn't return the JSON text, it returns a [`jqXHR` object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR). (And so when you pass that into `$.parseJSON`, it gets turned into a string like `[object Object]`, which is of course invalid JSON.)

The reason is that you set the `data` variable to the result of `$.ajax` call and return it. The return value of [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) is a `jqXHR` object.

But just changing that isn't sufficient, because the call is *asynchronous*; it completes *after* the function has already returned.

Your best bet is to modify `fetchData` to accept a callback, and then use the fetched data within the callback. Something like this:

```
fetchData = function(dataRequest, id, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/shows.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(dataRequest);
            console.log(data);
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Used like this:

```
fetchData('contentShows', this.id, function(showData) {
    var shows = $.parseJSON(showData);

    $.each(shows, function(index, value) {
        console.log(value.id);
    });
});
```